# Spring boot gradle project with kotlin setup issue

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

Hello i want to create a Spring boot app with kotlin and Gradle but i have this issue in the plugins line, it doens't recognize any plugin i add ,i couldn't undrestand what's missing, i'm using Gradle 6.3v , jdk 8 
Error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVAaD.png)

And that's the build.gradle file

[build.gradle.kts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZprnR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first plugin declaration has a typo in the version:

`kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.11"` needs to be `kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.71"`

I would start by changing that so all usages of kotlin plugins are aligned on a recent version.

If that does not resolve the problem, try running the build from the CLI with the added flag `--stacktrace` which may tell you more about *why* is the plugin not found.